# Why I am getting same string out put?

Tags: c++

I am not able to get the expected output for below function.

**in.txt file**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  StructEx.cpp
-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  Struct2ex.cpp
drwxr-xr-x  3 air  staff  app.dSYM
-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  MyStruct.cpp
```

> excepted - to print column 1 and column 4 contents from the above in.txt file. some thing like below

```
-rw-r--r--StructEx.cpp
-rw-r--r--Struct2ex.cpp
drwxr-xr-xapp.dSYM
-rw-r--r--MyStruct.cpp
```

> actual output -

```
-rw-r--r--tructEx.cpp
-rw-r--r--tructEx.cpp
-rw-r--r--tructEx.cpp
-rw-r--r--tructEx.cpp
```

the above output is wrong, what I am missing in below string stream function.

```
  void readingFromFile2(){

      ifstream inputFile("in.txt");
      string line;
      stringstream entireLine;
      char s = ' ';
        string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

      while(!inputFile.fail()){
        getline(inputFile, line);
        entireLine << line;
        entireLine >> p1 >> s >> p2 >> s >> p3 >> s >> p4 >> s >> p5 ;
        cout << p1 << p4 << endl ;
      }

    }
```

edit from important comments,  I think below function makes more sense, but still the same out put

```
void readingFromFile2(){

  ifstream inputFile("in.txt");
  string line;
  stringstream entireLine;
  char s = ' ';
    string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    char n ='\n';

  while(getline(inputFile, line)){
    entireLine << line;
    entireLine >> p1  >> p2  >> p3  >> p4  >> p5 ;
    cout << p1 <<  p4  << endl ;
  }
}
```

**Update - entire code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

void readingFromFile2();

int main(){
  readingFromFile2();
}

void readingFromFile2(){

  ifstream inputFile("in.txt");
  string line;
  stringstream entireLine;
  string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
  while(getline(inputFile, line)){
    entireLine << line;
    entireLine >> p1  >> p2  >> p3  >> p4  >> p5 ;
    cout << p1 << p2 << p3 << p3 << p4 << p5 << endl ;
  }
}
```

**Now it is working,** 
use `stringstream entireLine(line);`   instead of `entireLine << line;`

Comment: Unless you professor is insisting on using the iostream lib, make your life easier and use a regex. And never use the C++ iostream libs in the real world. They are horrid. (opinion obviously)

Comment: Parsing entireLine into strings skips spaces.  Try doing it without the "s" fields.

Comment: Streams already parse the empty spaces.  They don't need "extra help" by providing `s`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - without `s` also same thing repeating .

Comment: And `while(!inputFile.fail())` should be written as `while(getline(inputFile, line))`

Comment: I tried all above suggestion except regular expression. I am not getting what I am missing :(

Comment: @EdH: It's not about iostream. [Do not parse the output of ls.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There are API functions for querying that information, which are more reliable.

Comment: Don't reuse the same variable `entireLine`. Remove it and replace `entireLine << line;` with `stringstream entireLine(line);`.

Comment: thank you @molbdnilo Now its working.

Comment: @EdH https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using `>>` for stream input you should use

```
  entireLine >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> p5 ;
```

because spaces (`' '`, `\t` and `\n`) are ignored.

**UPDATE:**

Why "-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  StructEx.cpp" gives `tructEx.cpp` instead of `staff` when `entireLine >> p1 >> s >> p2 >> s >> p3 >> s >> p4 >> s >> p5 ;` is used?

Let's look step by step:

1) `entireLine >> p1`

string till the first space is read to `p1`: `-rw-r--r--` goes to `p1`

2) `entireLine >> s`

skips the space and `1` goes to `s`

3) `entireLine >> p2`

skips the space and `air` goes to `p2`

4) `entireLine >> s`

skips the space and `s` (beginning of `staff`) goes to `s`

5) `entireLine >> p3`

just reads `taff` to `p3`

6) `entireLine >> s`

skips the space and `S` (beginning of `StructEx.cpp`) goes to `s`

7) `entireLine >> p4`

eventually we have value for `p4` and this is `tructEx.cpp`, because `S` was taken at step 6) to `s`

**UPDATE 2**

Simplified demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line = "-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  StructEx.cpp";
    stringstream entireLine;
    char s = ' '; // not required
    string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    char n = '\n'; // not required

    entireLine << line;
    entireLine >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> p5;
    cout << p1 << ", " << p2 << ", " << p3 << ", " << p4 << ", " << p5 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives

[image]

But

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line = "-rw-r--r--  1 air  staff  StructEx.cpp";
    stringstream entireLine;
    char s = ' '; // initialization has no sense
    string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    char n = '\n'; // not required

    entireLine << line;
    entireLine >> p1 >> s >> p2 >> s >> p3 >> s >> p4 >> s >> p5; // HERE!!!
    cout << p1 << ", " << p2 << ", " << p3 << ", " << p4 << ", " << p5 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produces

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**

```cpp
void readingFromFile2(){

    ifstream inputFile("in.txt");
    string line;
    //stringstream entireLine;
    string p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;
    char str[51];
    while (getline(inputFile, line)){
        stringstream entireLine(line); //entireLine << line;
        entireLine >> p1 >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> p5;
        cout << p1 << p4 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working for you? Its not workin.  I tried it twice, dont know what exatcly wrong with me. thanks

Comment: And change condition in `while` statement

Comment: great for trying to explain me in detail.  But the problem is when I am reading from next line from the file it's not changing.  I have changed while but still, its get the same output

Comment: Yes, now its working. I changed to `stringstream entireLine(line);` from `entireLine << line` . Now its working like charm. If you update that in your answer could be helpful. thank you